# Minecraft plugin error in Eclipse (color, replaceall)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar, minecraft

I am editing a plugin that an owner hasn't updated for a long time and I get this error:

> The method `replaceAll(String, String)` in the type String is not
>   applicable for the arguments `(String, ChatColor)`

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        return false;
    }

    String prefixResult = getConfig().getString("prefix");

    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&f", ChatColor.WHITE);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&e", ChatColor.YELLOW);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&d", ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&c", ChatColor.RED);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&b", ChatColor.AQUA);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&a", ChatColor.GREEN);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&9", ChatColor.BLUE);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&8", ChatColor.DARK_GRAY);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&7", ChatColor.GRAY);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&6", ChatColor.GOLD);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&5", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&4", ChatColor.DARK_RED);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&3", ChatColor.DARK_AQUA);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&2", ChatColor.DARK_GREEN);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&1", ChatColor.DARK_BLUE);
    prefixResult = prefixResult.replaceAll("&0", ChatColor.BLACK);

    Player player = (Player) sender;
}
```

Do you have an idea what can cause this?

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshot.  The code in the picture is not visible to search engines.  That makes your post less useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that an import is not setup correctly from the author's source you are using.

Clearly, `prefixResult` is a String and [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is a known regex substitution method for Strings. Eclipse just sees you are referencing something in `ChatColor`, which probably doesn't exist, so it's resolving to that type.

To fix this problem, fix that import, letting you know that the type you specified cannot be resolved to a String.

However, I happen to know that Minecraft simply takes color characters `&e`, `&b`, `&c`, etc. and it converts them to the [Unicode color characters](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html). These are well documented.

So:

```
prefixResult.replaceAll("&e", ChatColor.YELLOW);
...
prefixResult.replaceAll("&b", ChatColor.AQUA);
```

is actually the same thing as:

```
prefixResult.replaceAll("&e","\033[32m");
...
prefixResult.replaceAll("&b", "\033[36m");
```

If you can't find `ChatColor` (which is probably the easiest solution), you could simply look up the values and directly substitute them in.

Hope this helps you!

**Update:**

Turns out, the `ChatColor` class is actually in the [Bukkit source](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/d3ab9468c3aed2a06c280bf6c9cea5108c736dcc/src/main/java/org/bukkit/ChatColor.java). Make sure you have the import:

```
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
```

somewhere in the file. But if you still have problems, and you're sure the project configuration is correct, you can supplement your code with that file directly. (Also, the color list is in there, you just have to figure out the pattern it uses.)

**Update:**

I finally looked at the [source](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/d3ab9468c3aed2a06c280bf6c9cea5108c736dcc/src/main/java/org/bukkit/ChatColor.java) more carefully and discovered that all you have to do is call the `toString()` method. This should return a String type because `ChatColor.COLOR` is an enumerated `ChatColor` type. Sorry I didn't notice this sooner.

So, I think your code should look something like this:

```
prefixResult.replaceAll("&e", ChatColor.YELLOW.toString());
...
prefixResult.replaceAll("&b", ChatColor.AQUA.toString());
```

Clearly, the `ChatColor` class defines the variable the `toString()` method returns when it instantiates the enumerated type [here](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/d3ab9468c3aed2a06c280bf6c9cea5108c736dcc/src/main/java/org/bukkit/ChatColor.java#L125):

```
this.toString = new String(new char[] {COLOR_CHAR, code});
```

Comment: wait what is this "\033[32m"); is that the color id?? well if it is then i need a list...

Comment: Yeah, that's the color ID. You can lookup the values from the link. If I get some extra time, I'll try to make a list. It would be a good reference for me as well, since I use them all the time.

Comment: could you make a list please

Comment: Yeah, I will try to make a list when I get a chance. Could you not get the `ChatColor` import working?

Comment: do you know a site that has the codes without like 1000 lines... just the color codes...??

Comment: Sorry. I finally figured it out. I updated my answer to explain conversion of enumerated `ChatColor` type to String. This should fix you problem. Sorry I didn't see this obvious issue sooner. I still might make the list for the sake of completeness.

Comment: You should simply write `prefixResult.replaceAll("&b", ChatColor.AQUA.toString());`

Comment: Feel free to up vote and accept the answer if it actually works / helps you!

Comment: wow a big problem when I insert the tostring it disabled like half of the imports so I wonder if it messes everything up.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "disabling the imports," but it shouldn't have any effect on that.

Comment: it does :3 ik that's wierd